# How to set the label count for X axis in LineChartView?

Tags: ios, linechart, ios-charts

In my data, I have hundreds of values for the x-axis, but I want to show only 6 or 7 of them at equal intervals so that my whole range of x-axis values are covered, but I am facing an issue as I am not able to show a limited number of values on the x-axis . I tried these

```
lineChartView.xAxis.spaceMin = 4 
lineChartView.xAxis.spaceMax = 7
lineChartView.xAxis.xOffset = 6 
lineChartView.xAxis.labelCount = 6
```

, but it is not working .Here is my screenshot for the display

[image: linechart view display]

Comment: Can you show us how you are adding DataSource in charts ?

Comment: @CodeChanger i got it right .I was doing a mistake in adding the data .Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The axis property `granularity` is used to specify the minimum interval between axis values. The default value is 1. Currently in my app i have it set to 0.5 to force all values to be displayed, but I only have 10 or so on the chart at once.

```
chartView.xAxis.granularity = 0.5
```

Perhaps setting this to a higher value will help you.